# derivative of tough matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I am not sure about the following derivative:

$ \frac{d\textbf{b}^T \textbf{E} \Omega \textbf{r} \textbf{r}^T \Omega^T \textbf{e}^T \textbf{b}}{d \textbf{r}} = ?$

where $\textbf{b} \in \mathbb{R^N}$, $\textbf{E} \in \mathbb{R^{N \times L}}$, $\Omega \in \mathbb{R^{L \times K}}$, $\textbf{r} \in \mathbb{R^{K}}$. Furthermore, $\textbf{r}$ is independent of all the rest.

My guess is that the derivative is

$\textbf{e} \Omega^T \textbf{E}^T \textbf{b} \textbf{b}^T \textbf{E} \Omega$

Is this correct?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you mean by the "derivative" of this function, and your guess only serves to make the situation more confusing. You have a function from $\Bbb R^K$ to $\Bbb R$, what exactly is the **shape** of the derivative that you expect here? For the usual definitions of the "derivative", the possible answers are $K \times 1$ or $1 \times K$, but the answer you give is $N \times K$.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could provide context beyond your arbitrary guess of what the answer is. For instance, how did you arrive at this guess? Where did this problem come up in the first place? Are there similar functions that you do know how to take the derivative of?

Comment: Hint: this looks like the derivative of $xx^T.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is really obscuring the main problem. For clarity, let's rewrite the vectors $b$ and $r$ as $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{r}$,resp., and the matrices $\Omega$ and $e$ as $\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ and $\boldsymbol{E}$, resp.

Assuming that $\mathbf{b}$, $\Omega$, and $\boldsymbol{E}$ are independent of $\mathbf{r}$, one can condense

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y} = \boldsymbol{\Omega}^{T}\boldsymbol{E}^{T}\mathbf{b}
\end{equation}

and thus rewrite the whole expression as

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}}\,\mathbf{b}^{T}\boldsymbol{E}\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{r}\,\boldsymbol{r}^{T}\boldsymbol{\Omega}^{T}\boldsymbol{E}^{T}\mathbf{b} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}}\,\mathbf{y}^{T}\boldsymbol{r}\boldsymbol{r}^{T}\mathbf{y}
\end{equation}

Defining $f(\boldsymbol{r}) = \mathbf{y}^{T}\boldsymbol{r}$ this reduces the problem to

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}}\,f(\boldsymbol{r})f(\boldsymbol{r}) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}}\,f^{2}(\boldsymbol{r}) = 2\,f(\boldsymbol{r})\,\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}}\,f(\boldsymbol{r})
\end{equation}

With $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}}\mathbf{y}^{T}\boldsymbol{r} = \mathbf{y}$ one obtains

\begin{equation}
2\,f(\boldsymbol{r})\,\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}}\,f(\boldsymbol{r}) = 2\,\left(\mathbf{y}^{T}\boldsymbol{r}\right)\mathbf{y}
\end{equation}